# Python 3 - **kwargs values can't be modified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value-store, keyword-argument

Practicing **kwargs notion in Python ,I wrote the following function :

```
def my_dictionary(**kwargs):
    for i in kwargs.values():
        i += 2
    return kwargs

print(my_dictionary(a=1,b=2))
```

I get the following output :

```
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Why didn't the values in kwargs changed, as instructed (`i += 2`) ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `**kwargs`, really. You'd see the same behaviour with *any dictionary*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ohh well ... everyone asks dumb questions from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only making an amendment to the variable `i` in your example.  You need to affect kwargs as so:

```
def my_dictionary(**kwargs):
    for k in kwargs.keys():
        kwargs[k] += 2
    return kwargs
```

Comment: yep, worked. Can't accept the answer for another 10 minutes for some reason .